# Json se convierte a array o solo un objeto pese a estar definido como array

Tags: javascript, angular, json, typescript

Os comento la situación:
Tengo el siguiente objeto (pongo solo los atributos necesarios para el problema):

```
export interface GlobalDonors {
  globalDonor: GlobalDonor[];
}

export interface GlobalDonor {
  id:           number;
  globalNumber: string;
  validFrom:    string;
  createdOn:    string;
  createdBy:    string;
  contributors: Contributors;
}

export interface Contributors {
  contributor: Contributor[] ;
}

export interface Contributor {
  lastChangeOn: string;
  lastChangeBy: string;
  matchReason:  null;
  localDonor:   LocalDonor;
}
```

Lo primero que hago es una llamada post de tal forma:

```
this.donorService.getGoldenDonorCrossReferences().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.goldenDonorCrossReferences = data as GoldenDonorCrossReferencesResponse
      });
```

Y en una función obtengo el siguiente json que se parsea correctamente:

```
{
   "globalDonors": {
    "globalDonor":    
    [
    {
      "id": 516,
      "globalNumber": "USA-0000000516",
      "validFrom": "2022-11-16T07:58:17",
      "createdOn": "2022-11-16T07:58:17>",
      "createdBy": "BKSHY",
      "contributors": {"contributor":       
      [
      {
         "lastChangeOn": "2022-11-16T07:58:17",
         "lastChangeBy": "BKSHY",
         "matchReason": null,
         "localDonor":          {
            "id": 136,
            "source": "GNS",
            "sourceId": "12266",
            "fullName": "Xsawi Ovtll",
            "dateOfBirth": "1978-03-16",
            "phone": "4330114202",
            "email": "tahcmk@aol.com",
            "identifiers":             [
               "Social Security Number: 085148924",
               "Social Security Number: 085148924",
               "Social Security Number: 085148924",
               "Social Security Number: 085148924"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "lastChangeOn": "2022-12-17T07:58:17",
         "lastChangeBy": "BKSHY",
         "matchReason": null,
         "localDonor":          {
            "id": 137,
            "source": "GNS",
            "sourceId": "12277",
            "fullName": "Testing McTest",
            "dateOfBirth": "1995-01-28",
            "phone": "533123555",
            "email": "yahoo@test.com",
            "identifiers":             [
               "Social Security Number: 085148924", 
               "DNI: 13672246X" 
            ]
         }
      }]}
   },{
      "id": 516,
      "globalNumber": "USA-0000000516",
      "validFrom": "2022-11-16T07:58:17",
      "createdOn": "2022-11-16T07:58:17>",
      "createdBy": "BKSHY",
      "contributors": {"contributor":       {
         "lastChangeOn": "2022-11-16T07:58:17",
         "lastChangeBy": "BKSHY",
         "matchReason": null,
         "localDonor":          {
            "id": 136,
            "source": "GNS",
            "sourceId": "12266",
            "fullName": "Xsawi Ovtll",
            "dateOfBirth": "1978-03-16",
            "phone": "4330114202",
            "email": "tahcmk@aol.com",
            "identifiers":             [
               "Social Security Number: 085148924",
               "Social Security Number: 085148924",
               "Social Security Number: 085148924",
               "Social Security Number: 085148924"
            ]
         }
      }}
   }]}
}
```

Hasta aquí bien, en mi función tengo el siguiente objeto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después intento recorrer estos objetos:

```
  this.goldenDonorCrossReferences.globalDonors.globalDonor.forEach(globalDonorElement => {
          globalDonorElement.contributors.contributor.forEach(contributorElement => {
            });
        });
```

Pero como podéis ver, pese a que mi atributo contributor está definido como un array

```
 contributor: Contributor[] ;
```

En la función estoy teniendo un solo objeto, no un array con un elemento, por lo tanto a la hora de hacer un .foreach funciona con el primer objeto que sí es un array pero falla en el segundo.
¿Cómo puedo forzar el parseo para que siempre sea un array? ¿Se debe hacer de otra forma este problema?

Comment: Pues... el problema es que la api te está devolviendo un único objeto ahí, por más que tú le digas a angular "Oye, aquí vas a recibir un array" si luego la API le devuelve un objeto... no hay mucho que hacer :) Es la API quien debería ser constante en la respuesta también. Comprueba si es un array antes de iterar por ejemplo: `if (globalDonorElement.contributors.contributor instanceof Array){ /* iteras */ } else { /* no iteras */ }`

Comment: ¿Y no hay forma de "forzar" que ese objeto se convierta a un array de un solo elemento de ese objeto?

Comment: Si claro, puedes mapearlo en el servicio para que siempre devuelva un array. Lo que no hay es (hasta donde yo sé), manera de hacerlo "automágicamente", es decir, te va a tocar programar esa conversión. Personalmente, yo lo mapearía en el service y punto, así "dentro" de tu aplicación siempre es un array, es lo más limpio.